# cannot show image in codeigniter

Tags: image, codeigniter, path

Actually, in my localhost, my website run without any problem.

However, in the living server, there are some problem of showing image.

If I put image in the web root, image can be showed in web. But if I put image into folder, image can't be showed.

Example:

```
/post/1/1.jpg
```

If I click the link directly:

> http://website/post/1/1.jpg

it will be error 403. As below:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /post/1/1.jpg on this server.
>       Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Discover some hints:

If I put all files into the web root, including codeigniter framework itself.
The website run without any problem.

However, it is not the good practice.  Actually, I want to put the codeigniter framework out of the web root.

Comment: check your htaccess, chmod the directory by 644 permission and check if the directory is the same as you mentioned in the post

Comment: Make sure the post directory is not inside the application folder.

Comment: you have to give a permission to image folder try 755 or 777

Answer (score 0):

Open your FTP via Filezila or any other program. navigate to your root folder and find the folder /post/ right click on it and change the select File Permissions... change it to 755 and re view the image in the browser.

Comment: I checked the files.  But all files are 755 in default

Comment: @Martin check your public html folder it is probably causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all reply.

I find the solution.

1) codeigniter framework can place out of web root without changing .htaccess file.

2) folder of image should be place under web root.

3) make sure the folder of image are 755 / 777 file permission.